# How to edit image in wix installer

Tags: wix

I need some advice on how can i edit the image in a wix installer. I tired searching the net but failed to have the proper answer.

[image]

Comment: [Check the excellent WiX tutorial page here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html) will give you the information on the built in dialogs. For your specific issue you want to set the WixUIDialogBmp variable.

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="path to your bmp"/>
```